STM32F401RE ADC Sampling time is very low
I am trying to detect zero crossings of a 50Hz sinusodial signal, with the ADC.
My code is like this, with a small offset I am trying to detect zero crossings and than give a small pulse just to see it.
while (1) {
/* USER CODE END WHILE */

/* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
    
    HAL_ADC_Start_IT(&hadc1);

    if (HAL_ADC_PollForConversion(&hadc1, HAL_MAX_DELAY) == HAL_OK) {
        Vout = HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc1)*3.3/255-1.65;
        snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%.5f \r\n", Vout);
        HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, (uint8_t*)buffer, strlen(buffer), HAL_MAX_DELAY);
            
        if (Vout >= -0.01 && Vout <= 0.01) { 
            HAL_TIM_PWM_Start_IT(&htim3, TIM_CHANNEL_1);
            HAL_Delay(1);
            HAL_TIM_PWM_Stop_IT(&htim3, TIM_CHANNEL_1);
        }           
    }
    
}

HAL_ADC_Stop_IT(&hadc1);

My ADC settings are like this

My clock configuration is like this

When I try it with something like 1Hz it can catch it, but even at 5Hz it misses. I don't know where the problem is maybe it has nothing to do with the sampling rate. I am just trying to detect zero crossings to give a pulse with a firing angle after a certain zero crossing.
Right now I am using signal generator, so there isn't much noise, but later on with network, it will be noisier, so the detection with an interval will probably not work. If you have another way, I can also try that.
Edit: With USART I tried to count samples, in half period of 50Hz sinusoid, there were approximately 20 samples.

why are you using ADC?

@jsotola What else can I use?

@BarbarosTeomanKosoglu The RM0368 Reference manual shows the ADC peripheral contains a analog watchdog feature allows the application to detect if the input voltage goes beyond the user-defined, higher or lower thresholds. Could you make use of the analog watchdog to generate an interrupt when a zero crossing occurs? A comment, and not an answer, since I haven't determined exactly how to do that.

@ChesterGillon I can try it tomorrow, but to detect crossing thresholds it still needs to read data doesn't it? So it will lead to the same outcome I think

That is the most complicated attempt tp detect a ZCS . Bravo. Have you tried aLPF, limiter then XOR gate with delay on 1 pin for the pulse width?

There’s many ways to do zero cross detection but analog sampling would probably be the least desirable - you’re doing a lot of work just to acquire the signal. How I’ve done it in the past is a  RC filter and a transistor. This gets fed into a timer capture channel on the micro. A software PLL is used to track the capture timing and to derive an internal zc value. The PLL is used to ignore jitter and transients from the mains and remove any phase shifts. The timer compare channels can then be used to output the trigger signals to the TRIAC/SCR/IGBT.

When doing three phase, I’d suggest sampling the ZC of each phase. Back in the late 1980’s I thought I’d be smart and derive the ZC from only one phase. It worked well, but caused issues when the units were installed - correct phase rotation Is not guaranteed on site and invariably was incorrect - necessitating swapping the phases. Subsequent designs had ZC circuitry for each phase.

I don't know the specs for your ZCS requirement but it seems over-complicated.
There must be an absolute V-level reference and an absolute time comparison to validate that the zero threshold has crossed and will not have multiple or missing pulses for the fundamental freq., to generate a fixed ZCS pulse at every zero crossing.  This avoids metastable and noise false signals.
Using a signal to detect the transition across your "zero" reference level can delay any value to generate a pulse width output of a binary XOR operation.  There may be input noise that is either filtered and/or you add hysteresis, which you then use to define these specs for SNR with Vp-p noise and BW with the range of AC signal frequencies and levels.
The limiter could be the MSB of your ADC or just a precision comparator to Vdd/2 or in my case a logic gate used as an AC amplifier and inverter with an XOR gate.
If the signal is AC coupled, normally the HPF cutoff is <=10% of the lowest signal for low phase shift and likewise for an LPF use >=10x the max freq. for the same reason.
Feel free to change any variables that determine the passband, pulse width and logic levels.


A HPF RC = 470k * 1uF dominates the breakpoint

A LPF RC = 47 * 1nF creates a noise filter

a LPF RC = 1k * 2.7nF creates the absolute time delay and output pulse width.

Ideal 3V logic was used.



My main purpose is to design a 3 phase sync switch. So after detecting zero crossings depending on a button value (for negative or positive cycle), after a certain delay angle, I want to give a pulse to the gate drivers and triggers mosfets. I tought this would be digitally easier

I'm not sure why you want to do that . Start here and modify  https://tinyurl.com/2cyofcby
